# Who reads the regex, Shell or the command?

Tags: linux, shell, command

The regex, we use to limit the results or for any other purposes, whom from are those interpreted, the command itself or the shell.

Comment: Can you please reformulate the question? I don't understand it. What regex command do you have in mind? `grep`, `sed`, `[[ val =~ regex ]]`? Something else?

Comment: As choroba indicated the answer to your question depends, entirely, on the context you are asking about. So you need to be more specific in terms of describing what context and usage you are asking about because you can get a meaningful answer.

Comment: OK, just to be simple, I'd list uncommented cron-jobs by, `crontab -l | grep -Evs ^# | cat -s` with squeezed spaces; Also, would the answers be different for all the exemplified 'grep' `sed` and the likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `ls *.txt | sed -e 's/[AB]/a/'` then the `*.txt` are interpreted by the shell (this is not a regex but is called globbing) and the regex `'s/[AB]/a/'` are interpreted by sed.

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs for more about how bash do it.